# Swift rand is not generating random numbers

Tags: swift, random

I put rand() in Xcode Playground and it prints the same number 16807 even I run many times and value did not change -> "16807"!
is this a bug?

```
print(rand())
```

Comment: Please review following link: http://iswift.org/cookbook/generate-a-random-number

Answer (score 2):

Mohamed Diaa,

You can make use of library functions like `arc4random()` or `arc4random_uniform()` for generating random numbers.

```
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
```

To get random value from 0 to 3

you might have to import Darwin to use it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mod` operations with RNGs. It leads to mod bias. `arc4random` has a parameterised version exactly for this and so you should always use `arc4random_uniform(3)` to generate a number from 0 to 3.

Comment: @fogmeister : I wasn't aware of it :) Thank you I'll keep in mind :) I'll update my answer :)